# $match is currently only supported when it is the first and only stage of the aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, linq, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have the following code which works locally:

```
public async Task GetConnections(string enterpriseId, IEnumerable<PermittedCommunicationType> permittedCommunication)
{
    IQueryable<ConnectionGetDto> query;
    query = await Task.Run(() =>
                from conn in _connectionCollection.AsQueryable()
                where (conn.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId)
                join consumer in _consumerCollection.AsQueryable() on conn.ConsumerId equals consumer.Id into joined
                select new ConnectionGetDto
                {
                    Id = conn.Id,
                    AdditionalData = conn.AdditionalData,
                    FirstName = joined.First().Profile.FirstName,
                }
                into p
                select p);

    query = ApplyEnterpriseConnectionPermissionFilter(query, permittedCommunication);

    var totalRecords = query.Count(); // Error when using Cosmos DB
}

private IQueryable<ConnectionGetDto> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<ConnectionGetDto> query, IEnumerable<CommunicationType> communicationType)
{
    if (permittedCommunication != null)
    {
        foreach (var p in permittedCommunication)
        {
            switch (p)
            {
                case PermittedCommunicationType.Call:
                    query = query.Where(c => c.PermittedCommunication.Call);
                    break;
                case PermittedCommunicationType.Email:
                    query = query.Where(c => c.PermittedCommunication.Email);
                    break;
                case PermittedCommunicationType.Im:
                    query = query.Where(c => c.PermittedCommunication.Im);
                    break;
                case PermittedCommunicationType.Letter:
                    query = query.Where(c => c.PermittedCommunication.Letter);
                    break;
                case PermittedCommunicationType.Sms:
                    query = query.Where(c => c.PermittedCommunication.Sms);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return query;
}
```

However - when I deploy it to Cosmos DB, at this line:

```
var totalRecords = query.Count();
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "_t": "OKMongoResponse",
  "ok": 0,
  "code": 118,
  "errmsg": "$match is currently only supported when it is the first and only stage of the aggregation pipeline. Please restructure your query to combine multiple $match stages into a single $match stage.",
  "$err": "$match is currently only supported when it is the first and only stage of the aggregation pipeline. Please restructure your query to combine multiple $match stages into a single $match stage."
}
```

This appears to be caused by the `ApplyFilter` method modifications to the query.

Does anybody know how I can restructure my query so I can still add optional arguments on after building the main part of my query?

Comment: Cosmos DB is not MongoDB. We really need not say any more on the subject. Just because someone wants to "claim" something works, does not mean that is actually true.

Comment: Could you expand on somebody "claiming" something works?

Comment: Bottom line is there "used to be" many sources where you could find out what Cosmos DB supports and what it does not. These have dissapeared from the Internet, and the same happens with any commentary here. You simply cannot expect something with is not MongoDB to behave exactly the same as MongoDB. Its an unreasonable expectation and an unreasonable claim. If you want to use Cosmos DB, then it actually has it's own API. If you want a MongoDB API, then the conclusion should draw itself.

Comment: I see. I don't suppose you know how to I could go about restructuring the LINQ query to work in this case?

Comment: Wrong animal. I've said what I am going to say as square pegs don't fit into round holes. MongoDB API Calls work perfectly "with MongoDB"

Comment: If you want to test CosmosDB locally I would recommend the Azure Cosmos Emulator. Cosmos really isn't Mongo in terms of performance or feature-set so you're better testing against something equivalent. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator